# Using moq to verify a call to a function with param parameters

Tags: c#, function, moq

I have an ILogger interface with LogTrace(string value, params object[] parameters). Now I want to verify that the LogTrace is called and the string to log contains some id. The problem is that it can be called differently. E.g.
1) LogTrace("MyString " + id)
2) LogTrace("MyString {0}", id)
and so on.

Is there a good way with Moq to verify all the scenarios? I can only think of creating a hand-made mock that will format the string that will be available for verification.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
mock.Verify( m => m.LogTrace( It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<object[]>() ) );
```

The `params object[]` is passed to the method as `object[]` anyway so you just have to match the array somehow (as above for example, this accepts anything).

If you need more control over the list, use the `It.Is` matcher which allows you to create your own predicate:

```
 mock.Verify( m => m.LogTrace( It.IsAny<string>(),
            It.Is<object[]>(ps =>
                ps != null &&
                ps.Length == 1 &&
                ps[0] is int &&
                (int)ps[0] == 5
            ) ) );
```

This example shows how to verify if the param list is not empty and contains `5` as the only parameter of type `int`.

Comment: I know that it's passed anyway, but this way I won't know if it did include an id that I want to see there.

Comment: This is how I did now, but this won't help if the logging method does pass id as parameter, but do something like "Id = " + 5. I just wanted to make it less fragile

Comment: @IlyaChernomordik: I don't understand. Could you possibly edit your answer and include a complete example example of what you'd want to accept and what you'd want to reject?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is an easy way for doing what you need here. The problem is that you need to ensure that a certain combination of values will be passed to your method, which results in many different verifiable scenarios:

- String contains ID AND parameters contains ID - pass
- String contains
  ID AND parameters does not contain ID - pass
- String does not contain
  ID AND parameters contains ID = pass
- String does not contain ID AND
  parameters does not contain ID - fail

However, Moq does not support this sort of conditional expressions between different arguments of your verifiable method. One possible solution is to check for the *absence* of an id, instead of its *presence* in either argument. Try something like:

```
mock.Verify(m => m.LogTrace(
    It.Is<string>(s => !s.Contains(id)), 
    It.Is<object[]>(o => !o.Contains(id))), Times.Never());
```

What we are doing here is verifying whether the *fail* condition is ever met - that is, your string does not contain an id, and neither does your object array. We use Times.Never() to make sure that this situation should never happen.

Keep in mind, however, that the code might not be obvious at first glance; make sure you properly explain your intent once you write it.

Comment: This is an interesting suggestion, but it's hard to verify logging is called 2 times for instance.

Comment: This is just a matter of including another Verify() for making sure that the method is called, either before or after this assertion. No matter how many times you call LogTrace, this test should ensure that the string logged will always contain the id. You should indeed write an additional assertion for making sure the method is called at least once.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use the `Callback`, but it get fairly convoluted (not tested):

```
var mock = new Mock<ILogger>();
string trace = null;
mock.Setup(l => l.LogTrace(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<object[]>()))
        .Callback((s1, par) =>
            {
                trace = string.Format(s1, par);
            });

//rest of the test

Assert.AreEqual(expected, trace);
```

If `ILogger` has a small interface, you might consider implementing a stub manually (that would keep all the lines it is supposed to log), and verify that at the end of the test. If you have multiple lines being logged than this will be a more readable setup.

Comment: It gets even more complex as it's not always called once, and that I need to verify as well. I just tested for now that my parameter is equal to the id but I am considering to write my own stub for this purpose